# How to remove HTML from CSV Export in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in wordpress and i am trying to export data from array, it works. but the problem is with the output it print HTML also.

So please help me to get rid of this problem.

Here is my PHP code that i try

```
public function export_data()
{
        ob_start();
        $filename = "export_data" . rand(1, 100) . ".csv";
        $export_data = $this->order_detail_items();
        ob_end_flush();

        $output = fopen("php://output", 'w') or die("Can't open php://output");
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-type: text/csv');
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        fputcsv($output, array('Store Name', 'Product name', 'Sell Quantity', 'Date', '(£) Total Price'));

        foreach ($export_data as $key => $data) {
            fputcsv($output, $data);
        }

        fclose($output);

        die();
}
```

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us sample of html ?

Comment: @ttrasn sure, i will show you, Please check the updated post

Comment: actually i didnt found `html` on your `csv`. can you tell me where is it? or can you take image ?

Comment: @ttrasn please check, now you can see the image

Answer (score 0):

First of all I see `java script tags` in your result.

you can remove this tags by :

```
 $html = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $html);
```

And you can remove your html tags with `strip_tags` function.

```
$html = strip_tags($html);
```

At the end. you can change your code to:

```
foreach ($export_data as $key => $data) {
    $data = preg_replace('#<script(.*?)>(.*?)</script>#is', '', $data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    fputcsv($output, $data);
}
```

Comment: But there is whole page html, start from `<html>` to `</html>`, how can i rid of this?

Comment: @RobinSingh You can remove tags with `strip_tags` function in php. which i used it in my answer